# Why do meshes "jitter" when rotating the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

I searched but couldn't find anything for this.

When I rotate the 3D View it "jitters". This is especially noticeable near the edges in Edit Mode.

[image: Jittering]

Does everyone else see that? What causes it?

Comment: I will affirm that is abnormal behavior.... what kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: Intel HD 3000 on Linux.

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah - As much as I enjoy linux, I've never used it for blender, so I can't diagnose any issues there unfortunately.. Your card _should_ be supported, provided your drivers are up to date, so I'm not certain it's that either. To be honest, I've never seen that behavior before. I'll upvote the Q, so maybe some more linux users will see.